# css vertical inline 2 inline-blocks in another inline-block

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

Check out this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/9S4zc/2/

1. How come this looks different in firefox vs chrome (the text is not aligned the same)
2. How do I ge the text in the inner:before element to be vertically aligned, preferably without line-height?

The dom looks like

```
<div class="middle">
<div class="inner"> Small text </div>
</div>
```

The css looks like

```
.middle {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 150px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.middle:before {
    content: '';
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.inner {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 25px;
    /* height: 30px; */
    text-align:center;
}

.inner:before {
    content: "Big Text";
    font-size: 50px;  
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 90px;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain in more detail (sketch?) how you want the two text elements to be positioned with respect to each other? Are the border boxes there for styling or demonstration?

Comment: I just checked out the fiddle in chrome and FF - and they both look the same

Comment: @Danield I see the same as you Chrome and FF render the same.

Comment: Also, why do you need to set `height:90px` on inner:before

Comment: look closely -- in FF the big text is closer to the top border than in chrome.  The end goal is everything vertically centered in everything else.

Comment: @Danield because it needs to be height 90px;

Answer (score 0):

The `inner:before` pseudo element is same as using a DIV element with `display: inline-block;` property.

Generally in CSS we use `display: table-cell;` property to have the content aligned vertically center or the **CSS Flex-box** for modern browsers, but in this case the display property is set to `inline-block`, which leaves no choice other than `line-height`(which you don't want to use) or some other hacks to push the content in middle.

As of my understanding, there is no another option for this. I am curious to know if anyone has a better explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Although you prefer not to use `line-height` it seems to be the best solution here.

Just replace `height: 90px;` with `line-height: 90px;` and everything is vertically centered. (Unless of coarse the big text is multi-line text - in which case line-height won't work)

**[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/9S4zc/4/)**

```
.inner:before {
    content: "Big Text";
    font-size: 50px;  
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid red;
    line-height: 90px; /* <--- */
}
```